# Unclickable Menu Item Label in Custom Menu with Clickable Children

Tags: menus

I need some help with a custom menu. I'm using WP 3.1.1.

I need to create an unclickable placeholder in the nav menu. So, the children will be clickable, but the "title" in the nav bar is not.

For example, let's  say I have a Shovel Page, Trowel Page, and a Spade Page and I want them all to be accessible under the Tools section in the Custom Menu. In the menu, "Tools" isn't clickable, only the children are.

I tried the solution outlined here: [non-clickable placeholder in the menul](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/non-clickable-placeholder-in-the-menu) . But, if I click the placeholder I get an Alert. Also, his opened Custom Link box looks different than mine. I only have options for URL, Navigation Label, and Title Attribute. I don't know if that has anything to do with why it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: What alert are you receiving? Your issue may be theme specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-clickable placeholder in the menu](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/non-clickable-placeholder-in-the-menu)

Comment: @Chris_O and @Milo, Thank you for the messages. I get "Alert The URL is not valid and cannot be loaded." Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Try just leaving it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE´S YOUR ANSWER

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unclickable-menu-button

CHEERS

Comment: Hi lili, Thank you for your suggestion. The link that I put in my question has the same solution. Unfortunately, it's not working for me.

Comment: I got it to work using your suggestion. Thanks for the help