# Making some links generated from the wp_nav-menu function unclickeable?

Tags: navigation

In this website:

http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/

I have a navigation menu taken from the twentyten theme. I want to make some links clickeable and some not (some don't have to behave like a link). I have accomplished this with some CSS but it doesn't work in all browsers.

The links are dinamically generated with:

```
wp_nav_menu
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why did I get a down vote?

Comment: probably because its not related to WP

Comment: @Ashfame the navigation bar (which uses Wordpress' php functions) of the twentyten theme is not related to Wodpress?

Comment: your question is about how to make links not behave as links. the source of the links is not that relevant, surely.

Comment: if you have to change how WP do something, then only it can be called WP related. If you are looking for a CSS/JS fix, stackoverflow.com might be better. Check my answer (js) to see if that does what you need.

Comment: [This question has been asked here many times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-clickable+placeholder)

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-clickable placeholder in the menu](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/non-clickable-placeholder-in-the-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom menu item in the admin panel with a dummy URL, foo.com or whatever. Add it to the menu, then delete the target URL and save. The menu item will be rendered without an href attribute and will be unclickable.

Answer (score 2):

Via the menu admin in WordPress you can add a custom class, say `no-link`, to the links you want to be unclickable. You may need to enable the custom class field via the display options.

Here's two ideas, based on jQuery. Note that the links will still be there for those with JavaScript disabled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your navigation ID
    var $nav = $('#navbar');

    // A. Completely remove the anchor element and replace it with a span
    $nav.find('li.no-link > a').wrapInner('<span/>').find('> span').unwrap('a');

    // or

    // B. Remove href attribute so nothing happens on click
    $nav.find('li.no-link > a').removeAttr('href');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use js to cancel the link behavior by returning false on click. This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link-id").click(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a link to behave like a link, then don't make it a link - ie remove the `<a> </a>` tags.

Comment: the linksa re dinmically added with wp_nav_menu

Comment: then don't use wp_nav_menu

Comment: I can't add them directly. The website if for a client. He must be able to add new links to the menu via `wp-admin`.